# How to trigger Toast on page load?

Tags: angular, angular6, primeng

I am trying to use a `<p-toast>` in my landing page to display notification messages when users login.

```
<p-toast position="top-center" key="tc"></p-toast>
```

The messages are then declared in my components.

```
ngOnInit() {

    // add toasts
    this.messageService.addAll([
      {key: 'tc', severity: 'info', summary: '30 Nov 2020', detail: 'Important message 1'},
      {key: 'tc', severity: 'info', summary: '30 Nov 2020', detail: 'Important message 2'}
    ]);

    // do other stuff

}
```

This doesn't work. To confirm that it is not a problem with my toast or messages, I placed the messages inside an `onClick()` event on the page and manually triggered it, which **does** work.

How do I get the Toasts to trigger on page load instead?

Comment: Have you tried in ngAfterViewInit() ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You have to send the messages once the view is initialized.

However, by triggering the messages in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook, you might get an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

Here are solutions to avoid this error:

First solution is using a `setTimeout` call to send the messages once everything is initialized.

> Here is a simple [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-toast-oninit)

```typescript
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.messageService.addAll([
            {key: 'tc', severity: 'info', summary: '30 Nov 2020', detail: 'Important message 1'},
            {key: 'tc', severity: 'info', summary: '30 Nov 2020', detail: 'Important message 2'}
        ]);
    })
}
```

Another solution is to force change detection using the `ChangeDetectorRef`  ([see this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)):

```typescript
constructor(private messageService: MessageService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.messageService.addAll([
        {key: 'tc', severity: 'info', summary: '30 Nov 2020', detail: 'Important message 1'},
        {key: 'tc', severity: 'info', summary: '30 Nov 2020', detail: 'Important message 2'}
    ]);
    this.cd.detectChanges()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Seems like that is a common enough error that I will do well to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)

The issue might be because the HTML is not yet rendered so try the following. This is an Angular Life Cycle hook that is only fired when the HTML has been initialized.

Be sure to add it to the class you are using it in like in the code snippet below, continue to use the `ngOnInit` for other logic that does not require HTML to be initialized and accessable.

```
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit, ngOnInit {

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.messageService.addAll(
    [{key: 'tc', severity: 'info',
    summary: '30 Nov 2020', detail: 'Important message 1'},
    {key: 'tc', severity: 'info',
    summary: '30 Nov 2020', detail: 'Important message 2'}]);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  //for other logic that does not require the HTML to be initialized.
  }

}
```

If you are having any issues with `ExpressionHasChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` then you could alternatively use a different life cycle hook that looks for the view to be initialized.

This would be [AfterContentInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentInit) and would be used exactly the same as the above example. Whichever works best for you given example. If the easiest solution is to setTimeout then go with that if it causes you no other issues. Would suggest using Angular to your advantage though whilst using the framework.

Comment: This might not be the optimal answer as it generates an `ExpressionHasChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, see my answer below.

Comment: I didnt see any errors from the blitz you made. Well two answer to choose from then :)

Comment: Yes, if you check in the console when there is no setTimeout, you will get the error.

Comment: I didnt get an error myself have added to my answer :)

Comment: ngAfterContentInit does not work either, I have tried it in my stackblitz

Comment: then your solution may be best

Comment: This solution does work on my end, thought I'll try out jo_va's answer as well before I mark as correct. In either case you have my upvote for a very informative answer.

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that anytime you fire off some task such as this from the ngOnInit, for example a toast message or other async call that need to wait for the Init to finish you can put your call right inline with the rest of your code as long as you use setTimeout. The ngAfterInit is not needed. You can thank (or curse) single threaded JavaScript for that.